# How do you handle conflict between Alpinejs and Vuejs in a laravel project

Tags: vue.js, templates, laravel-8, laravel-blade, alpine.js

Vuejs and Alpine js uses similar directive `@`

So i resorted to usin `x-bind:` `x-on:click` instead of using the `@` directive when writing AlpineJs in the same project as VueJs.

This has been working fine until
There's a need to do a loop.
Going through alpineJs docs

> There are two rules worth noting about x-for:
> x-for MUST be declared on a  element
> That  element MUST have only one root element

So when i do

```
<template x-for"(option, index) in options) x-bind:key="index">
//the rest of the code
</template>
```

I keep getting Alpine expression error: option is not define.

Any idea on how to resolve this?